# first array of getline is empty '\0'?

Tags: c++, delimiter, cin

I have this simple code and I used char because we are required to do use it and advised don't use string use array for now. its not the same but its similar This code is where i am getting the issue from

```
int main() {
    char province[2];
    char postalcode[6];
  
//** ON,n6n7y7** this is  the input
//Province is = ON and then postal code = n6n7y7
// the ',' should be discarded or ignored. and has to be typed all in one line as input

    cin.getline(province, ',');
    cin.getline(postalcode, '\0');
  

    return 0;

}
```

Postal code holds 6 charters, Province holds 2. Do I need a buffer for this is it with the delimiter it already being ignored

Why is it that the province side will take it properly as ON then hits the delimiter which is a ,
then the postal code doesnt. isnt it suppose to be get line and place it to postal code till it hits the empty string

Comment: Please note that C-style char array strings require a byte for the null terminator. Your `char province[2];` can only store _one_ letter. Likewise you can only store 5 characters in `postalcode`.

Comment: You've edited your code. Do you still have the issue?

Comment: I tried placing the null terminator, doesnt work still.

Comment: Recommendation: Always check the stream state after an IO transaction so that you can know that the transaction was successful or handle the clean-up if the transaction failed. You should find that after attempting to read 2 characters and a null into a 2 character buffer the transaction failed.

Comment: Side note: You should have kept Chris's suggestion. It solved at least one bug. Never assume that you have only one mistake. Often you have to untangle the mistakes before you can confirm that you fixed any one of them. A common mistake made by programmers new and old is to throw out a correct fix because it didn't solve the all of the problems or the problem they were trying to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my opinion, `istream::getline` (as opposed to `std::getline`) makes it far too easy to make the mistake you have, accidentally forgetting to pass the length, and taking what you're trying to pass as the delimiter, but using it as the maximum length to read (and using the default of `'\n'` for the delimiter.

If I had to use it, I'd write a little wrapper function on this order:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::istream &getline(std::istream &is, T (&array)[N], char delim = '\n') {
    return is.getline(array, N, delim);
}
```

This has the same number of parameters, but their types are enough different that you'll get an error if you try to pass one in place of another. The length (the one most people forget, just like you did) it deduces on its own (though this has one restriction: it requires that you pass an actual array--not, for example, a block of memory allocated with `new`).

Here's a bit of demonstration code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::istream &getline(std::istream &is, T (&array)[N], char delim = '\n') {
    return is.getline(array, N, delim);
}

int main() { 

    std::istringstream input{"ON,n6n7y7"};

    char province[3];
    char postal_code[7];

    getline(input, province, ',');
    getline(input, postal_code);

    std::cout << "province: " << province << ", code: " << postal_code << "\n";
}
```